# Script to include the required dll files to my installer

Tags: javascript, dll, vbscript, autorun

I got to have this kind of script that will automatically register the following dll files the computer need to run my program. Manual copying of the required dll into the system32 does not actually register that dll as what I saw, that's why I will try using a script that will run from autorun to register this dll. I heard about using "windows script host" but I find it hard to learn especially when it comes to registering dll file into system32. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Do you have list of all dlls? Or you just know the location of folder that has required dlls that need to move system32 folder for registration?

Comment: yeah. I have that kind of dll. I got it from my own system32. I knew this dll cause whenever I try to run my program into other computer that has no .net framework installed, it prompts the required dll. And when I try to just paste it into system32, it doesn't make change at all-- still has error. Somebody taught me to make use of a script to register automatically that dll into system32. You know the sript for that Mr 4M01?

Comment: But you want to copy this dll from one computer to another by script or what? & as you saying that you have that dlls in system32, are you selecting particular dlls or copying whole folder?

Comment: selecting particular dll only. And yeah, by script.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to create MSI package, it's easiest then you may expect.

Try advanced installer : http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html

You can use it free for simple projects like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down your problem:

1) Assuming that you have copied required dlls in a folder ( folderPath=path to this folder ) & you have list of dll files in "temp.txt" file in following format-

```
xolehlp.dll

xpob2res.dll

xpsp1res.dll
```

2) Copying dlls from one folder to system32 folder

3) Register this dlls

Here is the required code:

```
Option Explicit 
Dim oFSO, WshShell, oTxtFile, sLine  ,filePath, folderPath
Const ForReading=1


filePath ="C:\Documents and Settings\Amol\Desktop\Temp\FileList.txt"
'' Filepath is your local path to txt file

folderPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Amol\Desktop\Temp\"
'' folderPath is your path to folder from where you want to copy the dlls

 Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
 Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

 Set oTxtFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1) 


Do Until oTxtFile.AtEndOfStream 

   sLine = oTxtFile.ReadLine
   oFSO.CopyFile folderPath & sLine,"C:\WINDOWS\system32\"
   sLine = "regsvr32 C:\WINDOWS\system32\"&sLine
   WshShell.Run sLine

 Loop 
 oTxtFile.Close
```

Comment: is it a vbscript type of file Mr 4M01?

Comment: is it possible Mr 4M01 that the script will do the job of automatically copy the dll to "system32"? I mean, the script will run from an autorun and that script will copy that dll to system32 automatically. Is it possible through a vbscript?

Comment: code updated now in vbscript to copy the dlls from mention folder to system32 folder

Comment: whoa. that's really awesome Mr 4M01. Wait, another thing, can that script do multiple things? I mean, one: it will copy automatically the dll and second: it will run an exe file which is an installer.

Comment: Yes,its possible to run an exe file, what i have to say is that you can copy dlls from any folder, register it & then you can start with the installation...